# Area of a cap in a circular sector of a circle

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry

The area of the grey domain can be written using geometric understanding:

$$A = R^2 (\theta/2 - \sin\theta/2\cos\theta/2)$$

[image]

But I think we can find another expression:

$$A = 2\pi R^2(1-\cos\theta/2)$$

which is the height of the cap time the perimeter of the basal line (2a).

Can we write this? What conditions so that we can use the second equation?

Comment: The $\theta$ you refer to in the body, is marked as $\frac \theta 2$ in the diagram

Comment: *The height of the cap times the length of the chord* is the area of a rectangle, not a circle segment. If your second equation were true squaring the circle would be simple.